# Suitable Transport layer for Caching service

Tags: caching, microservices

Our use case is to design a micro-service for caching. This micro-service would use Redis as its back-end caching layer. Micro-service would first do some computation before storing the data to Redis. Now, as our micro-service provides capability to cache data, other micro-services should be able to use it for caching data. So, considering this use case, which transport layer (from other service to our caching service) should be better for us ? So far, our thought process has been that since we have to provide caching service, our transport layer should be fast enough. We have been thinking of below options 1. Websocket 2. Http2 3. GRPC (which is over http2) 4. REST (over http) - This might turn out to be very inefficient as it would have the overhead of creating and closing the connection for each request.

Any pointers on this would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As per the design and option you have mentioned above, I feel GRPC is the best way to achieve the required goal.